# Generating a dynamic 3D matrix

Tags: c++, dynamic, matrix

I need to generate dynamically a 3D matrix like this:

```
float vCube[8][3] = {
    {1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f}, {1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f},
    {-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f}, {-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f},
    {1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f}, {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
    {-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, {-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f}
};
```

I mean, to take a value and put it *inside* the matrix on running time.
I tried to make a pointer to float, then adding 3D elements by **new**, but the results were not what I want.

Note that I don't want to use STL like vector and so on, just a plane matrix.

Comment: Why do you not want to use vector?

Comment: 1) That's not a 3D matrix.  2) What's the formation rule?  3) What was the code your produced, what was the output, and why it didn't match your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use a `vector` or not, I would suggest you use:

```
struct Elem3D
{
   float v[3]; 
};
```

Then you can quite easily create a `vector`:

```
vector <Elem3D> cube(8);
```

or dynamically allocate a number of elements

```
Elem3D *cube = new Elem3D[8];
```

Working with two-dimensiona arrays without using `struct` or `class` quite quickly gets VERY messy both syntactically and "brainhurt".

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried, and the problem is that I need to give a pointer to a float[j][k], and the casting from the struct is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also store a 3D matrix in one dimensional array

```
 x = height
 y = width
 z = depth
 float VCube[x*y*z]
 a_ijk = VCube[i + y * (j + z * k)]
```

One interesting question is to know which solution (this or Mats Petersson solution) reduces cache misses if we want to do matrix operations

Comment: @MatsPetersson do you know which way reduces cache misses?

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a 2 dimension array first define the variable;

```
float vCube[8][3];
```

Then create a function that would initialize the vCube, or you can do the initialization in the constructor like this.

```
void function(float a, float b, float c) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j +=3) {
      vCube[i][j] = a;
      vCube[i][j+1] = b;
      vCube[i][j+2] = c;
    }
  }
}
```